How does this closure satisfy the trait bounds when it appears to drop a parameter
Hi I am looking over the documentation of asnyc_task and notice that in the example code:
use async_task::Runnable;
use flume::{Receiver, Sender};
use std::rc::Rc;

thread_local! {
    // A queue that holds scheduled tasks.
    static QUEUE: (Sender<Runnable>, Receiver<Runnable>) = flume::unbounded();
}

// Make a non-Send future.
let msg: Rc<str> = "Hello, world!".into();
let future = async move {
    println!("{}", msg);
};

// A function that schedules the task when it gets woken up.
let s = QUEUE.with(|(s, _)| s.clone());
let schedule = move |runnable| s.send(runnable).unwrap();

// Create a task with the future and the schedule function.
let (runnable, task) = async_task::spawn_local(future, schedule);

When it comes to the function signature for ::spawn_local(...) there is a trait bound on Schedule
pub fn spawn_local<F, S>(future: F, schedule: S) -> (Runnable, Task<F::Output>)
where
    F: Future + 'static,
    F::Output: 'static,
    S: Schedule + Send + Sync + 'static,

Where Schedule is the following trait:
pub trait Schedule<M = ()>: Sealed<M> {
    // Required method
    fn schedule(&self, runnable: Runnable<M>, info: ScheduleInfo);
}

It appears to me that the following code drops info: ScheduleInfo as an argument and so I am wondering how this trait bound is satisfied.
let schedule = move |runnable| s.send(runnable).unwrap();


There is an implementation for Schedule for all Fn(Runnable) that looks like this:
impl<M, F> Schedule<M> for F
where
    F: Fn(Runnable<M>),
{
    fn schedule(&self, runnable: Runnable<M>, _: ScheduleInfo) {
        self(runnable)
    }
}

